# Echo and Reject in FLEX

Tags: gcc, lex, flex-lexer

Below is a snippet of a FLEX program

```
%%
a     |
ab    |
abc   |
abcd  ECHO; REJECT;
.|\n  printf("xx%c", *yytext);
%%
```

Input:

```
abcd
```

Output:

```
abcdabcabaxxaxxbxxcxxdxx
```

Can someone explain how to get this output?

Comment: Did you mean to tag this w/ gnu-Flex or Lex?  It doesn't appear to be a question on Adobe/Apache Flex.

Comment: this program is to be compiled using command `flex ***.lex` and `gcc` on unix

Comment: I went ahead and re-tagged it for you.  Proper tagging can help you get answers to your questions.

Answer (score 5):

`REJECT` effectively causes `flex` to backup to the next-better match, bearing in mind the precedence rules for `flex`:

1. Match the longest possible token.
2. Of the tokens with the same length, prefer the pattern earlier in the source file.

In your case, the string `abcd` will match `a`, `ab`, `abc` or `abcd`; the preferred one is the longest one (`abcd`).

Since you have an `ECHO` action before the `REJECT` action, the `ECHO` happens even though the match will later be rejected. Eventually, `flex` will fall back to the default rule (which also matches `a` but is later in the source file), which will print `xxa` and accept the character. Now, nothing matches except for the default rule, so the next three characters get matched one at a time against it.

This would probably have been much clearer if you'd written `'\n'`s to stdout.